# How do you write an SQL query which uses multiple BETWEEN optimizations?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite and I would like to know how to generalize the following SQL statement so that inequality conditions can be imposed on an arbitrary number of columns, not just column `x`:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x BETWEEN xMin AND xMAX
```

I anticipated that this could be achieved in the following manner, but to no avail:

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE (x BETWEEN xMin AND xMAX) 
  AND (y BETWEEN yMin AND yMax) 
  AND (z BETWEEN zMin AND zMax) ...
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How did your attempt fail?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked just fine. What error are you getting?

And you don't need the parentheses around each between clause ...

Comment: I'm using SQLIte and I tried it in "SQLite database browser" on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @James R: I just tested _DB Browser for SQLite_ (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) on Windows and it woks fine as well. May be you can show us a little bit more of your code (table creation, `yMax`, `xMax`, ...)

Comment: The python code which generate thes db sets the type for every column to "text" -- could this be why its causing an issue? For example x is the literal "7" not the number 7.

Comment: @James R: That could definitely be, see updated answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement should work, e.g. with Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT 10 x, 40 y, 50 z 
          FROM dual) 
 WHERE (x BETWEEN 8 AND 12)
   AND (y BETWEEN 30 AND 42) 
   AND (z BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

See [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/736). With My SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT 10 AS x, 40 AS y, 50 AS z) AS t
 WHERE (x BETWEEN 8 AND 12)
   AND (y BETWEEN 30 AND 42) 
   AND (z BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

Another [MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/617), [SQLite Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/45), [PostgreSQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9) :)

***p.s.*** (update as per comment): take care, neither

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT "10" AS x, "40" AS y, "50" AS z) AS t
 WHERE (x BETWEEN 8 AND 12)
   AND (y BETWEEN 30 AND 42) 
   AND (z BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

nor

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT 10 AS x, 40 AS y, 50 AS z) AS t
 WHERE (x BETWEEN "8" AND "12")
   AND (y BETWEEN 30 AND 42) 
   AND (z BETWEEN 0 AND 100);
```

works. Both failed execution in *DB Browser for SQLite* ([sqlitebrowser.org](http://sqlitebrowser.org)).

Comment: Your first postscript is exactly what was causing my problem. Glad to know I'm not going completely mad.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in SQLite 3.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (x INT, y INT , z INT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (x,y,z) VALUES (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (4,5,6);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE (x BETWEEN 0 AND 5) AND (y BETWEEN 0 AND 5) AND (z BETWEEN 0 AND 5)
   ...> ;
1|2|3
2|3|4
sqlite>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Select * from t where x >=xmin and x <= xmax and y >=ymin and y<= ymax...
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on the RDBMS James R is using but if it's Oracle then that's the exact same thing as what he wrote. Oracle handles the BETWEEN condition of expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3 as (expr2 less than or equal to expr1 AND expr1 less than or equal to expr3). [Doc Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147)

Comment: First of all, i dont know which database is being used, he have said sql. My sql works

Comment: I wasn't aware that different RDBMSs have different 'flavours' of SQL.